# Espresso machine drain line keeps clogging

Tags: plumbing, clog

I have an espresso machine plumbed in for both water intake and drainage. The water intake is working fine, but the drain line that came with the machine keeps clogging. The symptom I'm observing is that the drain tray (that should be connected to the drain line) keeps overflowing from around where the drain line is connected (instead of through it) and creating puddles on the counter.

I checked the line and confirmed that:

1. There is a flat or slight downwards gradient at all points.
2. It's securely connected at all points.

I also never drain any thick coffee grounds, though small sediments probably get in there periodically when I'm clearing the portafilter or brewhead.

Why does this keep clogging? Is there something I can do differently to prevent future clogs?

Here are some pics. The drain line is the white / transparent flexible line. It goes from under the coffee machine, down through the countertop and into a cabinet, then sideways into the under-sink cabinet. In that last one, I make it do a slight loop to keep a downward gradient, then it connects to the sink's trap.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The third picture under the counter shows the line with a dip in it.  The whole line should have a slight downward slope in it.  Some string to hold that dip up might be enough.  I am assuming that drain is more like just a bit of water or drips than a decent flush.

Comment: Good catch, though I did experiment with this previously and even without that slight dip I seem to be getting clogs. At the moment, no matter how much I move the line, no water seems to be getting through the last half of the line, even though the first half is full of water.

Comment: And you're right that it's usually just dripping water and not a full flush.

Comment: Might need to take that line off every so often and clean it out.  Not sure if the black marks are just stains or where the pipe has stuff in it, causing the blockage.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As with "normal" drain lines, it should either be consistently sloped at 2% or so, (1/4" per foot, 2 cm/m) or vertical. You can see the buildup of materials that were left behind as the water ran away from them in several of the steeper sections here. A 2% slope will generally carry solids along, and at a vertical drop, they fall.

My experience with flexible hose drains is that they are prone to odd ways of airlocking due to small diameter and flexibility. I've had dehumidifiers with drain hoses attached and 20 feet of drop on the hose fail to flow due to a dip at the lower end of the hose, even though it would seem improbable for that to be possible. *When that floods the computer room it's clearly possible, however improbable it may seem.*

Thus, a larger, preferably  rigid drain is the way to improve your odds. A larger flexible drain would be better than this, and the point you are connecting to suggests perhaps a dishwasher drain line, but you'd still want to attempt to support it where it sould sag, and alter steeply sloping sections into vertical drops sweeping to 2% slopes. Changing most of it to 1-1/4" DWV pipe and fittings would be a more reliable approach.

You should also pour some clean water into the drain on a regular basis to help sweep out the fine grounds that are depositing.

Given the present lack of flow, you could start with stuffing a wire down it to see if you can get flow by "rodding it out" and then pour a large quantity of water through if you do get it open. *Or* disconnect the end under the machine and try blowing it out with pressure from the faucet. Moving the hose pulled far forward in the sink cabinet to cause the cabinet next to the sink to be more vertical and sloped than 45° could also help, if you support the hose where it should be sloped in both cabinets (*i.e.* put a board under it.)

Replumbing it would be the path to success in a longer term.

Comment: Instead of just pouring clean water into the drains, I'd suggest to collect the used cleaning solution the OP surely uses to clean the machine regularly. Or, for the first time, use a batch directly. The cleaners I'm familiar with work best if warmed up and left to sit in place for some time, then flushed with more cleaner, then finally with clean water.

Comment: It looks like above the counter—in addition to the low slope (and the belly where it goes into the tailpiece wye)—there may be a kinking problem where it penetrates the counter.

Comment: Additionally, I'm sure part of the problem is that this drain is likely to be very low flow, and low flow equals low velocity.  Low velocity tends to allow suspended solids (i.e. coffee grounds) to come out of suspension easier.